# How to create an unknown number of bs-sortable elements? Angular4 ngx-bootsrap

Tags: angular, angular-cli, bootstrap-4, ngx-bootstrap

Is it possible somehow to create bs-sortable element with `*ngFor`? When I try this (code below), the whole page in the browser freezes.

I want to create an unknown number of sortable elements. Which are sortable between themselves.

I'm using Angular 4, ngx-bootstrap, bootstrap 4, angularCLI

app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  items: string[][] = [
    [
      'Windstorm',
      'Bombasto',
      'Magneta',
      'Tornado'
    ],
    [
      'Mr. O',
      'Tomato',
      'Ketchup'
    ]
  ];
}
```

app.component.html

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items; let i = index">
  <bs-sortable
    [(ngModel)]="items[i]"
    itemClass="sortable-item"
    itemActiveClass="sortable-item-active"
    placeholderItem="Drag here"
    placeholderClass="placeholderStyle"
    wrapperClass="sortable-wrapper"
  ></bs-sortable>
  <pre>model: {{ items[i] | json }}</pre>
</div>
```

app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { SortableModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap/sortable';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    SortableModule.forRoot()
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create the number of bs-sortable elements.
But your list which is giving to [(ngModel)] should not have same keys.

For example:

```
list1 = ["test", "test1", "test2"] => it works properly.


list2 = ["test", "test2", "test2"] => it will freezes the browser.
```

For each "bs-sortable" you must have unique key's for [(ngModel)].